# Wi-Fi connection drops when downloading torrents, but wired connection still works

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bittorrent

After downloading for an hour or so, the Wi-Fi connection on my tablet stops working; forcing me to restart my router(it basically hangs when trying to connect).

This only happens when downloading torrents.

WIRED connection on my desktop PC with router still works fine; no issues at all.

I tired to lower the number of global connections to 50, but I still have the problem.
 I have also updated to the latest Linksys firmware.

One PC, a tablet and a smartphone.

I have COX cable.

Please let me know if you need any other info. Thank you!

Comment: How big are the files? Do you stream anything (movies/music) as well? What else are you doing when you're downloading the torrents? Have you ever tried downloading large files or doing any other network tests to ensure it's not your drivers wigging out due to how certain protocols work over wifi? ... Side note, it's also VERY possible it's just your router (regardless of firmware); I had an old Belkin router that did the same thing, turns out it was the hardware buffering system the WiFi chips used that would cause buffer timeouts (dropping my connections) :/ ..

Comment: 200mb to 4gig plus... I have tried both and save result. I have not done any tests. The router is somewhat new..it's a E1200,

Comment: I have done a speed test and get excellent results...same over wi-fi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi connection drops when using torrent clients](http://superuser.com/questions/587298/wifi-connection-drops-when-using-torrent-clients)

Answer (score 1):

When running bittorrent, your router can be rapidly deluged with thousands of connections.  Even if your software doesn't respond to them, the router still has to track them.  So, router slow-down/crashing is [not unusual](http://www.tech-talkers.com/index.php/2006/10/understanding-and-solving-the-bittorrent-slowdown/).  The solution is to limit connections and decrease timeouts.

If, [for example](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Router_Slowdown), your router were running DD-WRT v23 or better software, then you can proceed by entering the following values at 'Web-Admin -> Administration -> Management -> IP Filter Settings':

• Maximum Ports: 4096
 • TCP Timeout (s): 120 to 600
 • UDP Timeout (s): 120

Then save the settings and reboot.

Your router will likely be different, so adjust accordingly.

It is also possible that your router has new firmware available for download that may help.  It is good practice to keep your router's firmware up-to-date anyway: [it makes the NSA work harder.](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2013/09/nsa-router-hacking/)

If the above doesn't work or isn't available, you may want to upgrade your router hardware.  In discussion forums, bittorrent users seem to like high-end Netgear and Draytek (see [here](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=338312) for example).

An alternative solution, albeit not a pretty one, is to plug your router into one of those power strips that periodically power-cycles.  [Here](http://3gstore.com/product/2062_ip_power_remote_switch.html) is one currently selling for $99 that will do automatic reboots. [Here](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/17136766648551122467) is another model.  On google shopping, you can find many more.

Comment: Hello, so I need to flash DD-WRT v23 ?  Is that hard to do?

Comment: No, that was just an example.  I'd suggest looking through your router's config settings and try to find something similar.  Or, upgrade your router.  Or, get one of those power strips.

Comment: I can't find anything re: TCP/UDP timeouts

Comment: OK.  In that case, the only solutions that I have left involve hardware upgrades (see updated answer for info and links).  You may also wait in hopes that others here at _superuser_ have more ideas for your to try.

Comment: Ok great. All I do is upload the .bin file for my router correct? I found it on that site and it said my router was compatible.  Thanks so much

Comment: I would upgrade to DD-WRT only if you have found good instructions and are feeling technically adventurous.  If so, enjoy.  If not, you may want first to see if your router mfg has any firmware updates available.

Comment: I already installed the latest firmware.  I think I'll upload the proper bin file

Answer (score 0):

In case your router is using WMM QoS protocol, you might want to disable it or try switching to SSID QoS. Windows 7 and some other OSes are not going along well with WMM and causes the connections to be throttled (packages put on hold) while domain resolving still goes throught.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, including messing up with my wifi router advanced configuration, I've solved this issue by disabling UPnP, DHT, NAT-PMP and LSD on my client (Deluge).